# JMeter: From JDBC sampler result array to string

Tags: jmeter

In my JMeter test plan one of the JDBC sampler returns multiple values named `clusterCode`. Now i want to use this values in the next JDBC request like `select userID from users where clusterCode in ('foo1','foo2','foo3');`.

Currently I am using `JSR223 sampler` inside of ForEach controller of JMeter to append all the `clusterCodes` to a string. It is working correctly. But with this method number of JSR223 sampler request count is very high, and it is also taking a lot of time with higher number of users. Is there a better way to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution. I had tried to use `JSR223 post-processor`, but my implementation was wrong. I have got it working now. Following is the code:

```
var strClusterCodes1= "'" + vars.get("clusterCodes_1") + "',";
var msglength = vars.get("clusterCodes_#");

for (var position = 0; position < msglength; position++) {
    strClusterCodes1 +=  "'" + vars.get("clusterCodes_" + msglength) + "',";
}

strClusterCodes1 =strClusterCodes1.substring(0,strClusterCodes1.lastIndexOf(","))
vars.put("strClusterCodes",strClusterCodes1);
```

So, I find the number of elements in the array result with `clusterCodes_#` and append all the elements of the array with for loop to a string. And my work is done by a single `JSR223 post-processor`.